# Lumen: Handle error message inside a Service Layer

Tags: php, lumen

Im trying to create a service layer and Id like to throw error messages from my service class.

If I do the validation **inside the controller** it works as expected:

```
 $this->validate($request, [
            'nomeArtistico' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|unique:pessoas',
        ]);
```

Result:

```
{"email":["email@hotmail.com already exists"]}
```

But if I try to validate **inside a service**:

```
$validator =  Validator::make($request, $this->validationRules)->validate();
```

It only throws an 500 with an HTML default error message:
(1/1) ValidationException
The given data was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the `ValidationException` on your catch block and throw it like this

```
$rules = [
     'nomeArtistico' => 'required|max:255',
     'email' => 'required|unique:pessoas'
]

$messages = [
     'required' => ':attribute is required.'
];

try {
       $this->validate($request, $rules, $messages);
}catch (ValidationException $validationException) {
       throw $validationException;
}
```